# How to display data in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, database

I have this database schema which I can get from the api when it's successful.

surveys: array of survey objects containing:
(section_id, Course_code, Course_name, Department_id)

I want to display ***course_code*** and ***course_name*** only.
here is my code:

```
      export default function Dashboard() {
      const resp=await Axios({
      method:"Get",
      url:'http://localhost:5000/api/student/courses',
      headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json",
      },
      data:user,
      });
      const classes = useStyles();
      return (
     <GridContainer>
     <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
     <Card>
     <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
        <CardIcon color="warning">
          <Icon>content_copy</Icon>
        </CardIcon>
        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Available surveys</p>
        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>{resp.data.survey_count}</h3>
      </CardHeader>
      </Card>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
      <Card>
      <CardHeader color="primary">
        <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Available Surveys</h4>
        <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
          Here is the remaining courses surveys to submit 
        </p>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardBody>
        <Table
          tableHeaderColor="primary"
          tableHead={["Course Code", "Course Name", "Survey Link"]}
          tableData={[
            [
              //i want to map data here 
            ],
          ]}
        />
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </GridItem>
</GridContainer>
```

);
}

Comment: You need `useEffect` and `useState`.

Comment: As @bertdida has mentioned, you need to use ```useState``` to declare a state in React component. ```useEffect``` is to save the state when initial rendering. If you're asking about how you can map the data, you should check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.